# Make parallel file uploading ng2-file-uploader

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

I faced with the problem of uploading multiple files in parallel? 
Is it possible or the answer is found - link the proper site.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming this is about the below plugin
 https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Check this pull request, regarding multi uploading parallel this worked fine for me
 [https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/pull/630/files?utf8=%E2%9C%93&diff=split][1][pull request][1]
```